# I want to return a result in SPARQL only if a property exists and has a specified value

Tags: sparql, jena, owl

I have an owl ontology where I consider that a `Zone` element is tasked if it has an associated `Mission` and this `Mission` is `tasked`.

The `Zone`class in my ontology: `http://myontology/Zone`

- with the following object property: `http://myontology/hasMission` where the target is `http://myontology/Mission`
- and the following string data property: `http://myontology/label`

The `Mission` class: `http://myontology/Mission`

- with the following boolean data property: `http://myontology/tasked`

I want to know if a particular `Zone` is tasked. It means that it has the `hasMission` object property, and that the target `Mission` has a `tasked` data property with the value `true`.

I tried something like:

```
SELECT ?label ?tasked
WHERE {
  ?zone rdf:type myontology:Zone .
  ?zone myontology:label "ZoneName" .
  ?zone myontology:label ?label .
  ?mission rdf:type myontology:Mission .
  OPTIONAL { ?mission myontology:tasked ?tasked }
  OPTIONAL { ?zone myontology:hasMission ?mission }
}
```

Unfortunately if there is one tasked Mission in the ontology, I always get true for the `?tasked` variable, even if there is no `Mission` associated with the `Zone`, such as:

```
----------------------
| label | tasked |
======================
| "ZoneName" | "true"  |
----------------------
```

I would have liked to have this kind of result if the `Zone` is not associated to a `Mission`:

```
----------------------
| label | tasked |
======================
| "ZoneName" |   |
----------------------
```

What did I do wrong?

Note that I can't do:

```
SELECT ?label ?tasked
WHERE {
  ?zone rdf:type myontology:Zone .
  ?zone myontology:label "ZoneName" .
  ?zone myontology:label ?label .
  ?mission rdf:type myontology:Mission .
  OPTIONAL { ?mission myontology:tasked ?tasked }
  ?zone myontology:hasMission ?mission
}
```

Because in this case I the query will not return any result if the `Zone` is not associated with a `Mission`.

Comment: not sure if I get it because you didn't show real sample data in N-Triples or Turtle syntax. But `SELECT ?label ?tasked
WHERE {
  ?zone rdf:type myontology:Zone .
  ?zone myontology:label "ZoneName" .
  ?zone myontology:label ?label .
  OPTIONAL {?zone myontology:hasMission ?mission .
  ?mission rdf:type myontology:Mission .
?mission myontology:tasked ?tasked
  }
  
}` should at least always return the zone and if there is a mission the tasked value

Comment: You are right, I did not know that it was allowed to put several separate expressions in one OPTIONAL statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this query fix my problem, uninformeduser was right! :

```
SELECT ?label ?tasked
WHERE {
  ?zone rdf:type myontology:Zone .
  ?zone myontology:label "ZoneName" .
  ?zone myontology:label ?label .
  ?mission rdf:type myontology:Mission .
  OPTIONAL { 
   ?mission myontology:tasked ?tasked .
   ?zone myontology:hasMission ?mission 
  }
}
```

I think that the reason is because in my original try the two OPTIONAL are separate, so the engine look at them separately.